# Putting a condition for max values of a given problem

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

Table 1:

| city | wh | code | priority | category | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bangalore | xx | xx | xx | top_xx00 | 20 |
| bangalore | xx | xx | xx | campaign | 20 |
| bangalore | xx | xx | xx | top_400 | 20 |
| bangalore | xx | xx | xx | campaign2 | 20 |
| bangalore | xx | xx | xx | big_pack | 20 |
| bangalore | xx | xx | xx | top800 | 20 |
| delhi | xx | xx | xx | top_xx00 | 10 |
| delhi | xx | xx | xx | campaign | 10 |
| delhi | xx | xx | xx | top_400 | 10 |
| delhi | xx | xx | xx | campaign2 | 10 |
| delhi | xx | xx | xx | big_pack | 10 |
| delhi | xx | xx | xx | top800 | 10 |

Table 2:
combinations are based on item_class

| item_class | cutoff | qty | combination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

sample data for table 2:

[image]

Output table:

| city | wh | code | priority | combination | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I have the following query:

```
select a.city, a.wh,a.code,a.priority,b.qty,b.combination
from table_1 a
left join table_2 b on a.category=b.item_class
```

Now, for a particular city the value of combination in the output table should go till the maximum combination (max column in table1):
for example: for Bangalore in table1 it should pick all the values of cutoff, qty, combination from table2 till 20 which is max value for comb, as given in table1.
How do I put a condition for the above problem?

Comment: how are you using both mysql and postgres at the same time?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about use the row_number function.  partition by the city and order by the relevant columns that make your combination and pick the ones less than or equal to that row number.  something like

```
with t as (
  select a.city, a.wh, a.code, a.priority, b.qty, b.combination, max, 
         row_number() over (
           partition by a.city 
           order by a.wh, a.code, a.priority, b.qty, b.combination
         ) as rn 
  from table_1 a 
  left join table_2 b on a.category = b.item_class
) 
select * 
from t 
where rn <= max
```

Comment: what is this indenting with `*` and `t` on their own line?

Comment: I just popped it into some online sql beautifier but feel free to edit it any way you like.

Comment: ok -- I also fixed the two errors you had (which were easier to see when it was formatted)

Comment: @BryanDellinger can I put combination <= max in the where condition?